# Who can help to rediscover a free tool (from back in the day) that applies painted effects to images

Tags: image-editor

Okay, so about 10 to 12 years ago, I found a free Windows application that could apply painted effects to images.

I remember you could set the number of 'passes', and the brush stroke length or size.
And it had a preview pane.

I tried googling but didn't find it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I did find it after more googling: FotoSketcher.
At least I think it is, it's been modernized a bit, but the options feel very familiar.

Comment: A link to FotoSketcher would be nice as well

Answer (score 1):

There are options to produce a painted effect to an image in [G'MIC](https://gmic.eu/) *(this can be either standalone or a [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) plug-in).*

Both are free, gratis & open source, and available for Windows, OS-X, Linux and other platforms.

Example of the G'MIC watercolour in action:
[image: Linda G'MIC Watercolour]

Comment: Looking good, will surely try